# .PasteSpecial doesnt work for Range object

Tags: vba, excel

Y helo thar,

actually my vba-knowledge is quite good and normally I don't have many difficulties coding , but this is driving me nuts.

Code is pretty easy. I have a worksheet `PR_DB` where all my projects are stored. For every project there are a number of employees, saved in cells `(sel_pr, >10+)` (employee name and ID).

[image]

I want to delete an employee from the project and tidy up the project database entry. All employees are listed in two listboxes. The ones that are working in the project, and the ones that don't. Via the buttons I can add and remove employees from either listbox.

[image]

When I add an employee to a project (top button), my `Sub` just puts the ID&Name at the end of the row of said project. 
When I remove them from a project and therefore from the database, I look for the cell with the employee data. Afterwards I just want to cut all the cells to the right and paste them one cell to the left (via offset) so the deleted name is overwritten.

This is my code:

```
Sub delMA_from_prBetList()

    Dim i, j, k, listRow, lastRowMA_DB, lastRowPR_DB, sel_pr As Integer
    Dim wsPR, wsMA_DB, wsPR_DB As Worksheet
    Dim foundMA As Boolean
    Dim cutRng, pasteRng As Range

    Set wsPR = Worksheets("Projekte")
    Set wsMA_DB = Worksheets("MA_DB")
    Set wsPR_DB = Worksheets("PR_DB")
    lastRowPR_DB = wsPR_DB.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'check if any employee was selected
    If IsNull(wsPR.prBetListe.Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please select an employee."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    j = 10


    'look for selected project in DB 
    For i = 2 To lastRowPR_DB
        If wsPR_DB.Cells(i, 1) = CInt(wsPR.prListe.Value) Then
            'row ID of said project
            sel_pr = i
        End If
    Next

    'find employee

    Do Until wsPR_DB.Cells(sel_pr, j) = ""        
        'employees are saved as "ID;NAME"

        If wsPR_DB.Cells(sel_pr, j) = wsPR.prBetListe.Value & ";" & wsPR.prBetListe.Column(1, wsPR.prBetListe.ListIndex) Then
            'when found, look for last cell with an entry
            k = j
            Do Until wsPR_DB.Cells(sel_pr, k) = ""
                k = k + 1
            Loop

               'set cutRng so it spans from cell right to the found employee
               'to last cell with an employee in that project
                Set cutRng = wsPR_DB.Range(wsPR_DB.Cells(sel_pr, j + 1), wsPR_DB.Cells(sel_pr, k))
                'set pasteRng like cutRng, just one cell further to the left
                'so the deleted employee will be overwritten
                Set pasteRng = cutRng.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1)
                cutRng.Cut
                pasteRng.PasteSpecial


                Exit Do
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop

're-initialize listboxes     
Call init_maListe_dyn
Call init_prBetListe_dyn

End Sub
```

So whats the problem? Everything works just fine, all the cells I want to cut go into clipboard, but they arent pasted into the `pasteRng`. Error is 
`Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"`. I tried a thousand things but the solution is probably too easy to find.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

PS: I'm kind of in a hurry, so that text might not be as well formatted as it could be. Please bear with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use directly:

```
cutRng.Cut pasteRng
```

this should solve your problem ;)

Comment: Jeez.. thank you! But I still dont get, why .PasteSpecial doesnt work.

Comment: because `Application.CutCopyMode` needs to be 1 to use `Range.PasteSpecial`. I don't know for what reason this is, but you also can see that in the user interface: if you "cut" a range, the only option is to directly paste it somewhere... no specials aviable ;)

Comment: Alright, that brings some light in the dark. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to offset one column to the **left** it should be

```
Set pasteRng = cutRng.Offset(,-1)
```

Also, you're not defining how you want to paste. The paste settings may not be set to paste values if they were set differently prior to this instance (via code or otherwise). If you want to just cut-paste the values it would be

```
cutRng.Cut
pasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Let me know if that helps at all and if not I'll look further into it.

Comment: Woops, I tried the `1` for testing purposes, forgot to set it back. Edited it in the original post. `xlPasteValues` is just optional, so it doesn't have any influence on the method working itself. See answer above, that worked. But as I commented, I have still no clue why. But thanks anyways. :)

Comment: Ahh, very well. It's happened to us all, glad you found a working answer though :)